# Getting a pointer to an existing COM object?

Tags: c++, windows, com, credential-providers

How do you get a pointer to an existing COM object that has been created on the same machine, in a different process?

I have a [Credential Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx) which creates an object that inherits [ICredentialProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). ICredentialProvider has a method [SetSerialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I also have a service, from which I need to call the SetSerialization method of the Credential Provider. The thing is, I'm experienced in C++, but I'm a beginner with COM, so I don't know how. Microsoft's [sample 'CSampleProvider's](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5372) comments say to call the SetSerialization method from a 'remote client', but don't explain how - I assume they assume you know COM.

I've been reading [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and various [tutorials](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633/Introduction-to-COM-What-It-Is-and-How-to-Use-It) about COM all day, and I've got to a point where I can [create an instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of my Credential Provider in the service, but I need to get a pointer to the Credential Provider object that already exists, not create a new one, and I can't find out how.

How is it done?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't just run around stealing pointers from random processes. You have to arrange to hand the credential provider to the service. But let's take a step back. Why do you want to call ICredentialProvider::SetSerialization? Like the sample says, the method is there for the Remote Desktop Client so it can prepopulate the "Log on as..." dialog box when you connect. It's not clear why your service needs to do this.

Comment: @RaymondChen: 'You have to arrange to hand the credential provider to the service' - yes, that's what I need, but don't know how to do this in the COM world. The scenario is: we have 'x' amount of machines controlled by an 'instructor' machine, via named pipes that talk to a service which runs on the remote machines. The instructor needs to be able to lock/unlock all of the remote machines from a single button press at the instructor machine. I was under the impression that when requested by the instructor, I could call SetSerialization from the service to auto logon to the remote machines.

Comment: So maybe it looks as though I've been on a wild goose chase, and I will have to do something like pass the credentials from the service to the Credential Provider via some form of IPC, probably another pipe?

Comment: You need to set up some IPC between the credential provider and the service. But take a step back: Even if you got the pointer and wanted to call SetSerialization, what would you pass? (Note: I don't know either.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: I think I will send the username and password to the credential provider through a pipe, and from there let the credential provider deal with the serialization. If you want to summarise your comments in an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical method is via the [`Running Object Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That assumes the object has a "moniker", i.e. a COM name, and that this moniker is registered.

Note that the ROT is a form of IPC, specifically a systemwide directory of COM objects.

Comment: Perfect. Looks like exactly what I needed. I've implemented the pipe method already though and it's now working fine for my needs. I might not use the ROT method in this instance, but still, it's what I was looking for and very good to know for future reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Raymond said, in short, you can't - not by any built in COM functionality at least. If you must, it will need to be passed via some form of [Inter Process Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).